# Where are this flys coming from

Tags: bathroom

I wake up one morning for work and I'm walking down my hallway and there were 10+ fly's on my light .I just stayed away from them because it creeped me. I took my son to school came back about an hour later they were gone. About 4:30 that night I had been cleaning and washing clothes; I saw nothing but I went to my sons bathroom and there were 6 on his light and maybe 5 on the hallway light. I went back into the kitchen where I had been cooking for the past 45 minutes no flies and there's three on my light above the sink. Ok then the next day they were still in the house same place later.

That night my husband and I had had enough. we tried killing all of them. Well, they were all gone we thought. We sat down ate dinner walk into our boys bathroom and there were 6 on the light and 3 on the hallway light and 2 in our bathroom on the other end of the house.

I done with this. Please, any ideas? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Obviously there's a source of flies somewhere. Would you edit in a picture of one of the flies?

Comment: They have like a shiny blue color to them there bigger then the normal house flys and sometime theres bigger ones

Comment: I can't get a good picture but I went and looked they have shiny blue body

Answer (score 1):

Potted plants inside the house with soil that is not allowed to dry can be a source of small flies. Take all your houseplants outside and let them sit where they get some sun for a day or two, to dry out.

I have seen nasty maggots and flies in old sewer drains that are plugged or partially plugged, or that are left unused for long periods. Check all your drains; run hot water down through them. Check your basement if you have one.

Are your window screens and screen doors in good order? Flies will come into your house from outside during hot weather.

Comment: I have no house plants and all of are windows and door are screen and they stay shut and our house sits off the ground so we have something like a basement but only way in his outside

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the flies came inside on some fruit or veggie.  They came in as little larvae and then hatched as adult flies.  They did not all hatch at the same time, so after you killed the adults, some more hatched.  You are seeing them on the light bulb because flies like light.  Probably the problem wll go away as quickly as it started.  But flies can lay many eggs.  The eggs take about 2 weeks to turn into flies.  Look around and make sure there is no food out in the open where the flies could lay eggs and grow.